# trying to integrate stripe payment in php giving me json errors

Tags: php, html, json, stripe-payments

I am following the documentation to include stripe payment on my web application and I get the following error when I inspect element my page.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

this points to this line

```
checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      fetch("/daily-sub.php", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
```

however in my apache error log I get this error

```
Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_UgtiYTz1TvAO4B) Not a valid URL /vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php line 38
```

the error above points to this code

```
 $instance = new static($message);
```

all i am trying to do is create a simple checkout using stripe.

this is the code i have used to try and achieve this:

**checkout.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Buy cool new product</title>
        
        <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <section>
          <div class="product">
            <img
              src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
              alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
            />
            <div class="description">
              <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
              <h5>$20.00</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
        </section>
      </body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
        var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51Htt1MJsCP23BRielu7Sm8TYmxp1JFfh43Epik4adlxpcj853sj6BjBG0fd322IrtOABSebJHc0gfd32fdf6d00WYOrShjR");
        var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");
        checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
          fetch("/daily-sub.php", {
            method: "POST",
          })
            .then(function (response) {
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (session) {
              return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
            })
            .then(function (result) {
              // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
              // error, you should display the localized error message to your
              // customer using error.message.
              if (result.error) {
                alert(result.error.message);
              }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.error("Error:", error);
            });
        });
      </script>
    </html>
```

**daily-sub.php**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51Htt1MJsCP2rfedIBCr2zNH7qIecAqwEDQlxSOrfedVTBpXK4YlR323sdsskCC00Bdfd22EYxX');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'aud',
      'unit_amount' => 1,
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => 'Daily Subscription',
        'images' => ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
      ],
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => 'https:://google.com',
  'cancel_url' => 'https:://youtube.com',
]);

echo json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);
?>
```

Comment: I think you didn't install the Stripe PHP library properly.

Comment: @barmar I used composer for it and it said successful with no errors. Is there a way for me to check?

Comment: I misread the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
'success_url' => 'https:://google.com',
'cancel_url' => 'https:://youtube.com',
```

Neither of those are valid URLs as they have double colons.